# fb:flv problem with youtube videos

Tags: facebook

I am having a problem with using fb:flv for youtube videos. It works fine for videos stored in other places.

The code I am using is:

```
echo "<fb:js-string var=\"".$fvid."\"><fb:flv src='".$vidlink."' width='400'
height='300' title='my movie' color='#FFBB00' salign='r'
img='racersnation.com/facebookTest/ah.jpg' scale='showall'/></fb:js-string>";
```

where, $fvid=name of the video file
and
$vidlink=the absolute address of the flv file

This works perfectly ok for other flash videos stored on my server.

Also, auto run and image is not working here !

Can anyone kindly help me ?

Thanks.

-
ahsan

Comment: give an example of what you call a "absolute address of the flv file"

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXpWOKwkgVU          or          www.racersnation.com/some_folder/ahsan.flv

Comment: also, if the link is in error, it says, video couldnt be loaded !!! However, if the link is correct it doesnt do anything apart from showing the video loading icon for a few moments :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using :

```
 <fb:swf 
swfbgcolor="000000" 
imgstyle="border-width:3px; border-color:white;" 
swfsrc='http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxxx' 
imgsrc='http://img.youtube.com/vi/xxxxxxxxxx/2.jpg' 
width='340' height='270' />
```

Not sure why fb:flv was not working !

thanks everyone:)

-
ahsan